In an HTML document, how do I control how a PDF document is rendered to show page breaks and a margin?
I am trying to create a web page with an embedded PDF. My code works but it doesn't show breaks between the document's pages or a margin (in the same way that Chrome does when used as a PDF viewer). My problem is that I am too unfamiliar with handling PDFs in JS to find the documentation I need. I have tried googling for pdfjslib and pdf.min.js but the hits all refer to "PDF.js" which I am not using - I think!
Here is my code:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Set worker path to worker bundle of pdf.js
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.worker.min.js';
</script>
  
  <script>
    // PDF.js initialization
    const container = document.getElementById('pdfRenderer');
    const renderPage = (pageNumber, pdf) => {
      pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(page => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Set the scale for rendering
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });

        // Set canvas dimensions to PDF page dimensions
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render the PDF page into the canvas context
        page.render({
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        });

        container.appendChild(canvas);

        // Render next page if available
        if (pageNumber < pdf.numPages) {
          renderPage(pageNumber + 1, pdf);
        }
      });
    };

    pdfjsLib.getDocument('Fergus-pdf-small.pdf').promise.then(pdf => {
      renderPage(1, pdf);
    });
  </script>

Any pointers/suggestions greatfully received.

Thanks for very useful information. It is likely I can discect your fiddle to make progress although my problem is still that I can't find the documentation that explains the options for displaying the PDF in the style that I want: all pages in a scrollable vertical column, grey margin and gaps between the pages.
I will have a rummage through the code/web to see what I can find out.

Thanks again for the help. I will have a look in the folder but I'm really looking for some documentation/explanation. I can solve problems by examining code but it is hard work.
I'm trying to create a basic web page showing a PDF document. So, server I guess. And the examples give me disallowed MIME type errors?

Thanks again, but whilst your your advice is probably exactly what some people are looking for, it is too high-level for me to understand. I guess I am after either (a) a manual for PDF.js or (b) some working code for me to use/play with. NB you have already been kind to help and I am not expecting you to solve my problem per se. I can do some more research. Converations like this certainly help me narrow down my search - so thank you for that at the very least.
